# How to insert items dynamically in scroll area and loading the scroll bar in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Before we start things, this could be a possible duplicate of [Qt Scroll Area does not add in scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631462/qt-scroll-area-does-not-add-in-scroll-bars), however the answer provided by the user and which seemed to work for the OP, does not work for me. I fear it may have to do with versions, perhaps? Or am I missing something? (it is possible!)

Alright, for those who know Qt, I am a beginner and I have what seem to be a pretty silly problem, but is giving me a lot of headaches:

I want to press a push button and add items to a container, then it is supposed to be possible to scroll it down. As simple as that.

So I thought that perhaps setting a layout to scrollArea would do the job. It indeed adds my items as I wanted, but it doesn't load the scrollBar. I have checked the ScrollPolicy already, but nothing satisfied my issue. It is like the GVBoxLayout doesn't increase size and doesn`t let the scroll area to scroll.

Does anybody have a clue on how to fix it?

Code below:

saleWindow.h

```
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QListWidget>
#include<QString>

namespace Ui {
class SaleWindow;
}

class SaleWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SaleWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SaleWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();


private:
    Ui::SaleWindow *ui;
    QVBoxLayout *gBoxLayout;
    QMap<QString, QListWidget *>  m_mappings;
};

#endif // SALEWINDOW_H
```

saleWindow.cpp

```
#include "salewindow.h"
#include "ui_salewindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QLabel>
//#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
//#include <QtSql>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>


SaleWindow::SaleWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SaleWindow),
    gBoxLayout(new QVBoxLayout())
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Adding layout to scrollbar
    {

        ui->scrollArea_sales->setWidgetResizable(true);
        ui->scrollArea_sales->setLayout(gBoxLayout);
        QWidget *central = new QWidget;
        ui->scrollArea_sales->setWidget(central);
    }
}

SaleWindow::~SaleWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete gBoxLayout;
}

void SaleWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QGroupBox *sale = new QGroupBox();
    sale->setTitle("minha venda");
    gBoxLayout->addWidget(sale);
    ui->scrollArea_sales->setLayout(gBoxLayout);
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to set the layout to the scroll area, but to its widget.

Comment: So you mean I should do `central->setLayout(gBoxLayout);` instead? If so, it doesn't work as expected either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a QScrollArea for the scrollArea_sales object from the ui editor, you can see in the object inspector(qtdesigner) a default widget in the QScrollArea, so you not need to add this. Try this code:

```
// Adding layout to scrollbar(on the contrctor, replace yor scope by)
{
   ui->scrollArea_sales->widget()->setLayout(gBoxLayout);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {// on the slot replace all by:
  QGroupBox *sale = new QGroupBox();
  sale->setTitle("minha venda");
  ui->scrollArea_sales->widget()->layout()->addWidget(sale);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You have solved this issue! I didn't know the concept behind the structures (where can I properly understand it rather than the not-so-elucidative qt docs?).